# How to design short circuit and reverse polarity protection for PCB?

Tags: short-circuit, circuit-protection, reverse-polarity

I have read many posts and articles about short circuit and reverse polarity protection design for a PCB, but still I am quite confused about the industry standard/common principles here. The specifications for my PCB is:

PSU for input is 24V, 1.66A
The PCB have relay outputs controlling 24V solenoids, and also CAN bus 24V ports.

My question is how do I properly design short circuit protection for the outputs, and how do I design reverse polarity protection for the input?

Comment: I have no idea what a "CAN bus 24V port" is supposed to be? A connector with CAN signals + 24V supply in one?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Your assumption is correct: CAN signals, 24V and GND in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short circuit protection for outputs is conveniently handled by using "smart" MOSFET drivers with built-in current limits, short circuit protection, temperature protection etc etc. [Examples](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/smart-power-switches/high-side-switches/profet-plus-24v-automotive-smart-high-side-switch/). Additionally you'll need to have a flyback diode per solenoid.

Reverse polarity protection is commonly handled as shown in this answer: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/623011/6102.
A P-MOSFET is placed "in reverse" with drain towards +. The gate is pulled low with pull-down. This means very low voltage drop given that the R<sub>DS(on)</sub> will be very low. MOSFETs come in all manner of current and voltage ranges. In case of reverse polarity, the gate is no longer pulled down, the MOSFET won't conduct and + is disconnected from the circuit so that no current flows.
Optionally you can add a zener from source to gate as shown in the answer, to protect against overvoltages.

Comment: Aha, so for example the "ITS4200S-SJ-D" would be a suitable option to use per relay output/24V CAN bus port? Seems like a rather expensive solution to go with such MOSFET drivers. What do normal switch mode power supplies use? PTC elements?

Many thanks for the reverse polarity details.

Comment: @eidetech You'd pick one suiting your currents and there are multi-channel versions. The one you picked costs less than $0.7 @ 1k... if that's too expensive for you then what are you designing, some mass market consumer junk?

Comment: @eidetech Also you use these in place of relays, not to drive relays. That would be overkill indeed.

Comment: @eidetech SMPS are limited by design -- the *whole power section* browns out in event of overload, which has the convenient knock-on effect of resetting the control, and it takes a second or so before it restarts (thus implementing hiccup-mode limiting for free). This is harder to do when your source is external, and you presumably need logic to remain functional otherwise here :)

Comment: @Lundin Ah of course, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the detailed explanation.